# apt-get update error in Debian 11 "Temporary failure resolving" and also "Failed to fetch"

Tags: linux, ssh, apt, debian-bullseye

This is what I get when I run the apt-get update on my debian 11 server.

```
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://packages.sury.org/php bullseye InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'packages.sury.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'security deb.debian.org'
Err:5 htttp://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x bullseye InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.nodesource.com'
Err:6 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'repo.mysql.com'

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye/security InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch
```

Comment: Check your DNS resolve. Try in command line `nslookup deb.debian.org`

Comment: Romeo Ninov when I run 'nslookup deb.debian.org ' I get this reply: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Try to set your DNS to 8.8.8.8 for example and try again

Comment: @Romeo Ninov I configured the DNS to 8.8.8.8 but it doesn't work still getting same error.  The browser is not accessing the internet as well.

Comment: Do you have internet access at all on this machine?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov it seems that I do not have internet access at all, the server was connected and working fine until Monday when an administrator was installing company specific software and lost ssh connection,  since then there is no internet connection or ssh connection and I cannot apt-get update. Can you suggest some configuration that I can use to get it up and running again please

Comment: talk to whomever is responsible for your DNS server and/or your network and configure a working DNS server.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider thanks, will do and give feedback

Comment: I can ping 8.8.8.8 and the other 3 servers but I cannot ping Google.com or extract downloads from other url's on the internet and the internet browser has no internet access. Reply "failure name resolution" 

Server3 is cluster 3 and static IP /61

GW is /57 which is cisco switch 1. Switch 1 interconnected to Cisco router 1 and Router 2, FW 1 is currently bypassed. VIP /58. Still " FAILURE NAME RESOLUTION "

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

Comment: Nice, my problem solved